# What do 科 and 頼母しけれ mean here?

Tags: classical-japanese

> 言語を慎みて多くす可らずとは、寡黙を守れとの意味ならん。諺に言葉多きは**科**少なしと言い、西洋にも空樽を叩けば声高しとの語あり。愚者の多言固より厭う可し。況して婦人は静にして奥ゆかしきこそ**頼母しけれ**。福澤諭吉の「女大学評論」より

What does 科 work there?

What does 頼母しけれ mean? Here's a online dictionary explains:

[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/頼母子講/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E9%A0%BC%E6%AF%8D%E5%AD%90%E8%AC%9B/)

> 金銭の融通を目的とする民間互助組織。一定の期日に構成員が掛け金を出し、くじや入札で決めた当選者に一定の金額を給付し、全構成員に行き渡ったとき解散する。鎌倉時代に始まり、江戸時代に流行。頼母子。無尽講。

May I interpret it as women help each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to furigana [here](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000296/files/43029_23560.html) and [this entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%A8%80%E8%91%89%E5%A4%9A%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AF%E5%93%81%E5%B0%91%E3%81%AA%E3%81%97-2236158), this 科 is the same as 品 (しな), and it means something like "grace", "nobility" or "fineness". 言葉多きは科少なし means "Being chatty is being undignified".

> ##### [しな【品／<sup>▽</sup>科／<sup>▽</sup>階】](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%93%81_%28%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%29/#jn-99274)
>
> ７ 人の品格。人柄。品位。「さぶらふ中に―心すぐれたる限りを選 (え) りて」〈源・若菜上〉

頼母しい is just an *ateji* for 頼もしい ("trustworthy", "reliable"). 静にして奥ゆかしきこそ頼母しけれ is 静かで奥ゆかしいことが頼もしい(のだ) in modern Japanese (notice the ～こそ～けれ [*kakari-musubi* pattern](https://chu.benesse.co.jp/qat/981_j.html)).